# Get statistics for each day of the week mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like this

```
Click ID   |    click_user_id | click_time (timestamp) 
-----------------------------------------------------
1          |      1           |       1518810765
-----------------------------------------------------
2          |      2           |       1518845445
-----------------------------------------------------
3          |      2           |       1518945445
-----------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get how many clicks I have received for each day of the week (using mysql).
The results should look like this:

```
"mon":50
"tue":20
.
.
.
"sun":100
```

Thank you.

*Edit:

- 1.If the day has no records it shows 0
- 2.Not limiting to a single week (show results for every Monday ever recorded)
- 3.Output is not really important. The days can be represented as numbers as well. Tabular form is also OK.

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  What should happen if a day has no records?  Are you limiting your query to a single week (which week?), or, for example, do you want the Monday sum of clicks to represent every Monday you ever recorded?  Will tabular output be fine or do you need the three-letter weekday short form to be in double-quotes, concatenated with a colon, concatenated with the count?

Comment: @pilcrow edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the `click_time (timestamp)` to a day of the week.

MySQL provides some useful functions. `FROM_UNIXTIME` and `DATE_FORMAT`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

As a demonstration:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME( 1518945445 ),'%a') AS day_of_week
```

We can replace the literal with a column reference in

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME( t.click_time ) ,'%a') AS day_of_week
     , t.*
  FROM a_table_like_this t
 WHERE ...
```

---

To get a count for each distinct value of `day_of_week`, we would do that the same way we would get a count by `click_user_id`

```
SELECT t.click_user_id 
     , SUM(1) AS cnt
  FROM a_table_like_this t   
 WHERE ...
 GROUP BY t.click_user_id
```

just replace the occurrences of `t.click_user_id` with the expression that returns `day_of_week`.

To get the result formatted as specified, consider using an outer query using the `LOWER` and `CONCATENATE` functions.

For ordering the rows, consider adding another expression that returns ascending values of day of week e.g. `DATE_FORMAT( ,'%w')`

```
SELECT CONCATENATE('"',LOWER(v.day_of_week),'":',v.cnt) AS foo
  FROM ( 
         SELECT ...     AS day_of_week
              , ...     AS cnt 
              , ...     AS daynumber
           FROM a_table_like_this t
          GROUP BY ...
       ) v
 ORDER BY v.daynumber
```

Comment: above and beyond

Comment: "FROM a_table_like_this t" -that cracked me up a bit xD.Thank you for your detailed answer, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This may hurt the eyes a little bit, but we'll join the following:

- `data`: The grouping of counts per weekday from your data
- `weekdays`: A derived table of weekdays' names *and* their (ODBC) order

The second tables supplies rows for any theoretically "missing" days from your data.  The way we implement it also lets this work regardless of your locale.  (My Monday is "Monday", but yours might be "poniedziałek".)

```
SELECT weekdays.dow, COALESCE(num_clicks, 0) FROM
       (SELECT DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(click_time)) AS "dow",
               COUNT(1) AS "num_clicks"
          FROM tbl
         GROUP BY 1) data
 RIGHT JOIN
       (SELECT DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL i DAY) AS dow,
               DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) AS dayorder
          FROM numbers
               WHERE
               i BETWEEN 0 AND 6) weekdays
       ON
        data.dow = weekdays.dow
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY weekdays.dayorder ASC
```

That `numbers` table has a single column `i` whose INT values range from zero to ... something greater than 6.  If you don't have a numbers table, you could do it yourself in a derived table:

```
...
-- Let's start with the first Sunday in recorded history:
(SELECT DAYNAME("1970-01-04") AS dow, 0 AS dayorder
  UNION ALL
 SELECT DAYNAME("1970-01-05"), 1
  UNION ALL
 ...)
```